# Logic App Designer Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

testing logic apps today and ran into an odd issue

steps to recreate:
logic app > logic app designer > schedule connector > New Step

azure function > create new function > next

function authoring > enter function name > create

unable to continue "unexpected end of json input"

normally I write functions in C# so was going to circle back on the function logic

[image]

Comment: the intention was to use the outlook connector to trigger workflow when a new email arrives.  i tested with a few connectors and found the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spoke with microsoft, they said it could have been a temporary issue, i belive it may have to do with the json input that was not serialized when selecting variable from a previous input.  either way, resolved now.